# Vulkan delete pipeline after recording command buffer

Tags: lifetime, vulkan

Is it safe to first pre-record a command buffer and then dispose of a pipeline that it uses? And what about other components that were used during creation of the command buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vkDestroyPipeline`'s valid usage rules [clearly state](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkDestroyPipeline.html):

> All submitted commands that refer to `pipeline` must have completed execution

So no, you can't just throw away a pipeline because you recorded some usage of it into a CB. And this is true of virtually every object which gets recorded into a CB.